# Enterprise Architect Exception on reading element.notes

Tags: c#, exception, enterprise-architect

I am currently working with reading the requirement element’s description using EA C# add-in. The requirement element is shown below:

[image: Requirement element]

I had read these notes from excel and written it as description for the requirement element. When I try to fetch these notes and write it back to excel using the element.Notes API I am getting below exception and notes is returning NULL value.

When checking in excel I found that a group separator is present between the >> symbol and full stop in demo>>.

[image]

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would definitely help if you post the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try  **[*GetFormatFromField*](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/repository3.html)** of repository class .

Something like

```
 // for getting plain text from EA
 >  Repository.GetFormatFromField("TXT",theElement.Notes);
```